# Modify John Resig's microtemplating engine to replace "new Fun" or "eval"

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, jquery-templates

How can I modify [John Resig's microtemplating](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) engine so that it should not use `new Func or eval`. I want the same behavior but without `new Func`:

```
/ Simple JavaScript Templating
// John Resig - http://ejohn.org/ - MIT Licensed
(function () {
    var cache = {};

    this.tmpl = function tmpl(str, data) {
        // Figure out if we're getting a template, or if we need to
        // load the template - and be sure to cache the result.
        var fn = !/\W/.test(str) ?
      cache[str] = cache[str] ||
        tmpl(document.getElementById(str).innerHTML) :

        // Generate a reusable function that will serve as a template
        // generator (and which will be cached).
      new Function("obj",
        "var p=[],print=function(){p.push.apply(p,arguments);};" +

        // Introduce the data as local variables using with(){}
        "with(obj){p.push('" +

        // Convert the template into pure JavaScript
        str
          .replace(/[\r\t\n]/g, " ")
          .split("<%").join("\t")
          .replace(/((^|%>)[^\t]*)'/g, "$1\r")
          .replace(/\t=(.*?)%>/g, "',$1,'")
          .split("\t").join("');")
          .split("%>").join("p.push('")
          .split("\r").join("\\'")
      + "');}return p.join('');");

        // Provide some basic currying to the user
        return data ? fn(data) : fn;
    };
})();
```

Comment: And you want to do this why? Are you afraid of script injection?

Comment: Because chrome extensions doesn't allow me to do that (new FUN). It gives me "Uncaught Error: Code generation from strings disallowed for this context" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968234/chrome-extension-uncaught-error-code-generation-from-strings-disallowed-for-th

Comment: In the future, you can create a sandbox: https://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/sandboxingEval.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see an easy solution. You really need to evaluate the string that comes out of the 'str...' in order to make it work. So yes, it becomes either eval, or Function or anything similar.

If you want to do without, you need to discard the idea of John that you parse the template into a JS string that is then evaluated... :)

Comment: Nope. It gives the output as "< items.length; i++) { var item = items[i]; p.push('
', item.UserName,'" instead of parsed HTML.

Comment: Been looking at it some more, I don't see an easy solution. You really need to evaluate the string that comes out of the 'str...' in order to make it work. So yes, it becomes either eval, or Function or anything similar. Edited my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

For obvious performance reasons, many template engines compile template into function that uses data as parameters and process them with generated JS code, instead of running expensive template parsing on each output and implementing own expression engine. Generally, the only way to get rid of compilation is to rewrite engine completely or use another one, so no, it is not possible to just "modify" it.

However, as you need it to make it working in Chrome, you can convert your own code instead to make use of [lower privileged sandbox, designed specially to run code with `eval` and like](https://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/sandboxingEval.html).