# google maps api does not work in google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-chrome-extension

I am making a google chrome extension using JavaScript, HTML, CSS. For this I need to read longitude and latitude of an address provided by a user. While testing my extension I am keep getting below error

[image: Error]

Here is my js code

```
result: {
            data: function (from, to, hrs, mins) {
                fromaddress     = from;
                toaddress   = to;
                hours       = hrs;
                minutes     = mins;

                View.result.readLatLng();
            },

            readLatLng: function () {
                //var addressone = document.getElementById("addressone").value;
                geocoder    = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                geocoder.geocode( { 'address': fromaddress}, function(results, status) {
                  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.latitude;
                    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.longitude;
                    console.log('lat: ' + latitude + ', lng: ' + longitude);
                  } else {
                    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                  }
                });
            }
        }
```

and here is my manifest.json file

```
{
  "name": "Name",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": { 
    "scripts": [
      "js/result.js",
      "js/script.js"
    ] 
  },
  "description": "Desc",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/icon.png",
    "default_title": "Title",
    "default_popup": "html/popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [ 
    "http://*/",
    "https://maps.google.com/*",
    "https://maps.googleapis.com/*",
    "http://localhost/*",
    "geolocation"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com https://maps.gstatic.com; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Please help me how can I solve this?

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968234/chrome-extension-uncaught-error-code-generation-from-strings-disallowed-for-th

Comment: Yes I read that one. I am not using any templates in my extension. So that does not help.

Comment: @Marcelo could you please provide any help to me? Thank you in advance

Comment: I know about Google Maps and their API, but I know nothing about Chrome extensions.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Maps API loader uses document.write() and apparently that is not allowed in Chrome extensions. See [***here***](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4201):

> I use your maps in my extension for Google Chrome. Now I try to switch
>   to Chrome Extension manifest.v2 and found that Content Security Policy
>   is required to use.  But your code contains "eval" function use and
>   document.write to load scripts, so your maps can't be initialized.

Comment: But I am not using document.write() method anywhere in my code.

Comment: You're not using it, but the Google Maps API is. Look at this source: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false

Comment: Did you look at the link I posted in my answer? It's been posted as an enhancement request and acknowledged by Google in the issue tracker. You can star the issue to give it more weight.

Answer (score 0):

I too had problems with the Google Geocoding API when building a web app.  A potential issue with your code that I can see right away deals with how you get the lat and lng.

Try this instead:

```
var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
```

Comment: When I ran your code I got "undefined" for both latitude and longitude.

Comment: OK. I changed my code according to your suggested one but I am still getting the same error.