# Google Maps API conflicts with Chrome extension policies

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-maps-api-2

Iam currently working on a extension for chrome. My extension should contain the Google Maps API. If i try to lunch my extension I get this error:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://maps.google.com/?file=api&v=2.x&key=KEY&sensor=true&callback=initialize' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".
```

- I have an API Key
- I set permissions to:  `"permissions":"https://maps.google.com/*"`
- I changed the CSP a few time. If set CSU to the APIs url like above I got something like this: `Refused to load script because it because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://maps.google.com/?file=api&amp".'`
- I tried to set the parameters to `&sensor=true` & `&callback=initialize`

I also read a lot of old request wich are similar to my case, but I does not find anything that could be helpful.

I would be glad if someone could help me, thanks :)

Comment: How about using V3 instead of V2.

Comment: @EmmanuelDelay I could, but I think I would have the same issue

Comment: API v2 is deprecated since about 2012, and any requests for `v2` will really just use v3 anyway, but with possibly limited functionality.  Read: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2tov3

Comment: As I read in some comments: "Thanks Google, for ruining my summer".  Google Maps changed its policy.  Things that worked for years suddenly didn't work anymore.  Now, any question asking us for V2 solutions ... well, forget it.  You have to move on.

Answer (score 0):

One possible issue here is that you did not correctly set the content security policy for Google Maps URL. You should change your `"content_security_policy"` in manifest file to look like this:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com https://maps.gstatic.com; object-src 'self'"
```

For more information, you can check these threads on how to solve this kind of error:

- [Content Security Policy and Remote Scripts](http://blog.syedgakbar.com/2012/09/content-security-policy-and-remote-scripts/)
- [Content Security Policy: cannot load Google API in Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129077/content-security-policy-cannot-load-google-api-in-chrome-extension)
- [google maps api does not work in google chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245251/google-maps-api-does-not-work-in-google-chrome-extension)

Comment: It doesn't work with me, it shows me this: https://www.screencast.com/t/eLAvOHRmA